# $wpdb not working, even though validation comes back positive

Tags: php, wordpress

I wonder if anybody can help me. I'm trying add some data to a table within a wordpress database. I'm using the $wpdb class and every time I run the code, the validation I got in place comes back positive. But when I check the table in the database, it's empty.

My Code:

```
    // Define global $wpdb
    global $wpdb;

    // Retrieve information from the form
    $location = $_POST['txtLocation'];
    $price = $_POST['txtPrice'];
    $type = $_POST['sltType'];
    $revenue = $_POST['txtRevenue'];
    $surgeries = $_POST['txtSurgeries'];
    $tenure = $_POST['sltTenure'];
    $upload = $_POST['txtUpload'];

    // SQL statement to insert information from the form into the database
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO practices ('Location', 'Price', 'Type', 'Revenue', 'No. of Surgeries', 'Tenure', 'PDF') VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", $location, $price, $type, $revenue, $surgeries, $tenure, $upload);

    $result = $wpdb->query($sql);

    if (!result) {
        echo '<p class="sql-error">There was a problem uploading the practice to the database</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="sql-success">The practice was uploaded to the database</p>';
    }

    echo $wpdb->last_query;
```

Does anybody know why my code is doing this???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forgot a closing `)` in your query.
Here

```
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s 
                            ^
```

Try:

```
 $sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO practices ('Location', 'Price', 'Type', 'Revenue', 'No. of Surgeries', 'Tenure', 'PDF') VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", $location, $price, $type, $revenue, $surgeries, $tenure, $upload);
```

Also it is

```
if (!$result) {
     ^
```

Comment: Nope still doesn't add data to the database

Comment: Changed the $result mistype and it's coming up with "There was a problem uploading the practice to the database"

Comment: Just debugged and i'm getting: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Location', 'Price', 'Type', 'Revenue', 'No. of Surgeries', 'Tenure', 'PDF') VAL' at line 1]
INSERT INTO practices ('Location', 'Price', 'Type', 'Revenue', 'No. of Surgeries', 'Tenure', 'PDF') VALUES ('Newport','56,000','nhs','876,000','1','freehold','http://www.oneguard.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/139-FIRST-FlOOR.pdf')

Answer (score 0):

In addition to closing the `VALUES` statement in your query as has been suggested, you might find that referencing the column names using `'` would also give you issues.

MySQL expects column identifiers to be enclosed using backticks: `.